# Python installed version no showing (Python 2.7.10)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed python version 2.7.10 using the below steps.

```
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.10.tgz
cd Python-2.7.10
sudo ./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

and set the environment veriable to

> export PATH=~/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/python:$PATH

but when I run python in the shell. Default version shows as Python 2.7.6

```
root@SUP-DIGINBENCH:/# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How can I sort this issue ?

Comment: `~/usr/local/lib/` is an odd looking file path... Are you sure that should not be `/usr/local/lib/` instead?

Comment: And you can run `which python` to validate your `PATH` is set correctly

Comment: `which python` shows this

`root@SUP-DIGINBENCH:/var/www/html# which python
/usr/bin/python`

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is the default system Python. You've not set the PATH correctly

Comment: @cricket_007 this how I set the path. 
`export PATH=~/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/python:$PATH`

Comment: Please read my first comment again

Comment: I am new to this field. Can you instruct me on how to solve this @cricket_007 ?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Aside: If you are just starting to use Python, then Python3 is recommended. And 2.7.10 is an outdated version, anyway...</sup>

Try running `python2` or `python2.7`...

If those don't work, then check Python can be ran with the full path you expect

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/python --version
```

If not, you probably want to configure to install to the correct place, `/usr`, **not** `~/usr` or the current folder

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
sudo make
```

Then, your `PATH` needs to instead be more like so

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10
export PATH=$PYTHONPATH/bin/:$PATH
```

And you set these within the `~/.bashrc` (if you have one; if not, then one of those start-up scripts that you can see with `ls -a ~/`)

Then the values are persisted across reboots and sessions.

After you edit the `~/.bashrc` file, you must `source` it to have those values available.

```
source ~/.bashrc
python --version # should work
```

Answer (score 0):

1.type `which python` to find where is the python2.7.6 (e.x. `/usr/local/bin`)

2.type `ln -s ~/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/python /bin/python` to add the link to Python2.7.10 and then rename or delete the old python version  (e.x. `rm -f /usr/local/bin/python`)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you used

```
sudo make altinstall
```

it did not replaced your previous python path.

Try this

```
sudo make install
```

and you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian derivatives such as Ubuntu, use APT:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
```

On Red Hat and derivatives, use yum:

```
$ sudo yum install python
```

On SUSE and derivatives, use zypper:

```
$ sudo zypper install python3
```